# Input Pattern not working in multi-step react form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

As you can see in this form [Website](https://taxifrontend.herokuapp.com/rider/signup) when we're at first part of form we aren't told that we've not entered valid email|(or any other data is entered correct) but in second part(after pressing submit on the first form ) we're told that input doesn't match the pattern. How to bring this to first part as well.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Rider_Signup = () => {
  const [step, setstep] = useState(1);
  const [formdata, setFormData] = useState({
    zipcode: "",
    email: "",
    name: "",
    location: "",
    dob: "",
    phone: "",
    sex: "",
    password: "",
    aadhar: "",
    village: "",
    post: "",
    ps: "",
    block: "",
    pnumber: "",
  }); // use to hold input from user
  const onSubmitform = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error");
    }
  };
  const renderForm = () => {
    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <div className="admin_form_div">
            <h1 className="form_header">Hey Admin! </h1>

            <center>
              <form id="admin_form" name="admin_form">
                <label for="Email" className="label">
                  Enter the Email
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="Email"
                  className="Email"
                  value={formdata.email}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, email: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  placeholder="email@id.com"
                  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"
                  title="Please enter valid email"
                  required
                />{" "}
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="password" className="label">
                  Enter the password!{" "}
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  className="input"
                  value={formdata.password}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, password: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"
                  title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"
                  required
                />{" "}
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="Phone" className="label">
                  Enter Phone
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="tel"
                  name="Phone"
                  className="input"
                  value={formdata.phone}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, phone: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  placeholder="9876543210"
                  pattern="[0-9]{10}"
                  title="Must be 10 digit number"
                  required
                />{" "}
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="Name" className="label">
                  Enter Name{" "}
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="Name"
                  className="input"
                  value={formdata.name}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, name: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  placeholder="Name"
                  required
                />{" "}
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="aadhar" className="label">
                  Enter aadhar{" "}
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="aadhar"
                  className="input"
                  value={formdata.aadhar}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, aadhar: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  placeholder="AAdhar"
                  maxlength="12"
                  minlength="12"
                  title="Enter a Aadhar"
                  required
                />{" "}
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="DOB" className="label">
                  Enter D.O.B{" "}
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="date"
                  name="DOB"
                  className="input"
                  value={formdata.dob}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, dob: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  required
                />{" "}
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="Sex" className="label">
                  Enter Sex{" "}
                </label>
                <br />
                <select
                  name="Sex"
                  id="Sex"
                  value={formdata.sex}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, sex: e.target.value });
                  }}
                >
                  <optgroup label="Gender">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                  </optgroup>
                </select>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="Place" className="label">
                  Enter Place{" "}
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="Place"
                  className="input"
                  value={formdata.location}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, location: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  placeholder="Place"
                  required
                />{" "}
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="Zipcode" className="label">
                  Enter Zipcode{" "}
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="Zipcode"
                  className="input"
                  value={formdata.zipcode}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, zipcode: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  placeholder="000000"
                  pattern="[0-9]{6}"
                  title="Enter a valid Zipcode"
                  required
                />{" "}
                <br />
                <br />
                <button onClick={() => setstep(step + 1)}>Submit</button>
              </form>
            </center>
          </div>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <div className="admin_form_div">
            <h1 className="form_header">Hey ! </h1>

            <center>
              <form
                action="/initial"
                id="admin_form"
                name="admin_form"
                onSubmit={onSubmitform}
              >
                <label for="village" className="label">
                  Enter the village
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="village"
                  className="village"
                  value={formdata.village}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    console.log(formdata.village);
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, village: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="post" className="label">
                  Enter the post
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="string"
                  name="post"
                  className="Emails"
                  value={formdata.post}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    console.log(formdata.post);
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, post: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="ps" className="label">
                  Enter the ps
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="string"
                  name="ps"
                  className="Emails"
                  value={formdata.ps}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    console.log(formdata.ps);
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, ps: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="block" className="label">
                  Enter the block
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="string"
                  name="block"
                  className="Emails"
                  value={formdata.block}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    console.log(formdata.block);
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, block: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="pnumber" className="label">
                  Enter the pnumber
                </label>
                <br />
                <input
                  type="string"
                  name="pnumber"
                  className="Emails"
                  value={formdata.pnumber}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    console.log(formdata.pnumber);
                    setFormData({ ...formdata, pnumber: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </center>
          </div>
        );
      default:
        return <div></div>;
    }
  };
  return renderForm();
};

export default Rider_Signup;
```